# use file name substring to get mimetype and then use it to setType for Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, operating-system

I got an application that lists some files in some layout and then implemented a single file click listener which is supposed to make the android system suggest apps to handle the File. Now , i got multiple file types in the layout, some apps are supposed to get video applications suggestions while others need text editor apps. There is this Intent method called `setType(String s)`, which is supposed to filter possible apps that can handle the file. So I figured this is some kind of `mimetype` that acts as an application pointer. S i decided to get a `substring` of the last three characters in any file name and use it as parameter in the `setType(String s)` method like this

```
   Uri uri= FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".provider",myfile);
   String mimety= StringUtils.right(myfile.getName(),3);
   Intent handle= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
   handle.setType("'"+"/"+mimety+"'");
```

I then added some `FLAGS` to the Intent and called `startActivity` but logcat is throwing this error that

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ='/pdf' flg=0x10000000 }
```

When i tap on a file that has `.pdf` extension. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is your uri ?? u passed in intent

Comment: Hold on i edit my question

Comment: There is my uri

Comment: you have no apps that support pdf file thats why u got this error

Comment: I do have them, WPS office etc

Comment: Is there some way in which i can switch the substring and set mimetype like if(string.endswith(charsequence){ //set appropriate mimetype}

Comment: my setType above is missing application attribute like `"video/mp4'`

Comment: debug your code and let me know the value of mimety ?

Comment: Doing that in a moment

Comment: From the logcat, mimety is `pdf`